# How to reinitiate class on duplicated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, hover, marquee

I am trying to get a new site up and going.

I am using this jQuery plugin to create some infinite scrolling elements:
https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee

And i am using this for hover effects (images):
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2018/11/27/image-reveal-hover-effects/

It's working somewhat fine. On all the initial elements, the hover works fine, but the hover effect doesn't take effect on the duplicated elements in the marquee. All the elements get created, it just doesn't fire when you hover.

The strange part is, that the effect does get applied to an element, as soon as new duplicate is created.

You can see it in action her:
http://thinkbear.net/demo/index-demo.html

I can trace it to this, which doesn't fire on duplicated elements... well not until a new duplicate is created anyways.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-fx="4"] > a, a[data-fx="4"]')].forEach(link => new HoverImgFx4(link));
```

So my question is, how do i get it to fire on duplicated elements?

I was thinking something like this:

```
$( '.marquee-left').hover(function(link) {
        new HoverImgFx4(link)
    });
```

Or listening for when duplicated items appear, then firing it.

You can see the full version her:
http://thinkbear.net/demo/index-alt.html

I know it's a mess with vanilla js and jQuery, but code isn't my first language.

Kind regards
Jens

Comment: doesn't look like the plugin has an option to do that - perhaps you need to edit it and add your own callback function for after the elements are cloned

Comment: How would i go about doing that?
Updated my question with what i have tried.